# Unable to record ios mobile app on Jmeter

Tags: iphone, jmeter, load-testing, configure

I want to perform load test of ios mobile app using Jmeter but I am facing issues in configuring my mobile phone. I have installed Jmeter and added recording template in it and set the port no of HTTP Test script recorder to 8888. I have also installed and trusted the certificate in my mobile device and set the proxy settings of my device by giving IP and port no. But after setting proxy I am unable to access the internet. Apps as well as other websites on chrome etc stops working due to loss of internet and when I remove proxy it starts working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is wrong without seeing [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) preferably with [debug logging enabled for the proxy components](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (it's located in JMeter's "bin" folder)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```

A "blind shot": in order to provide Internet access to the iOS device JMeter must have Internet access itself. Try adding a [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and a [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler manually pointing to some site in the Internet which works for sure, i.e. http://example.com may be a good choice. Then add a [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and run the test. If the test fails it means that JMeter cannot access internet and most probably you need to [configure it to use your corporate or ISP proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server)

If the test is successful - look into the log files for JMeter and [iOS](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/obtain-ios-device-logs-using-mac-and-windows/) and try to figure out the cause of the problem from them. If you fail to do this yourself - either update this thread with your configuration details and log files or ask a new question